# No internet connection on Android emulator

Tags: android, internet-connection

When i use an AVD with Android 4.0.3 specified as target I can use the browser and view the pages. But when I use Google API as target I have no connection(i get the next error: "This application requires a working data connection"). I start both AVDs with the same parameters:
C:\Users\blahblah\android-sdk-windows\tools>emulator.exe -avd AvdName -http-proxy http://123.456.789.123:5678 (Not the actual proxy adress =) ). What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you set the needed permission for your application?

Comment: I understand what are you talking about, but sadly this is not the case. I am just trying to start the preinstalled Maps application or the browser and I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you can see the 3g symbol in the top bar.
If not go to Settings> Wireless & Networks> Mobile Networks>
and check whether Data enabled is checked, If it is not checked do it.
Else simply press F8.
Since you started the AVD with proxy address this must be the problem.

Comment: Pressing F8 did it. I accidently pressed F8 while emulator in focus +1.